# Why they have different between Android and IOS device simulator when register user with Firebase?

Tags: react-native

I'm making an application using React Native and Firebase (Firebase Realtime database and Firebase authentication), I found the different when build the same code on ios and android simulator specific as my case: with this code I used it to register new user account with firebase and get the user uid after registered. The result I got from android simulator is my expectation but with ios simulator I cannot get the user uid after register with this code (see the log below please).

```
_onRegister = async () => {
        console.log("register clicked")
        console.log("before register userid: " + this.props.userID)
        await this.props.registerNewUser(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        this.setState({
            isLoading: true
        })
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false
            })
            console.log("after await in _onRegister: " + this.props.userID)
            if (this.props.userID != '') {
                alert("Đăng kí thành công")
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
            }
        }, 10000)

    }
```

the log of android simulator:

```
register clicked
register clicked
before register userid: 
in registerUser
Registering with account: test2210@gmail.com-12341233
after await in _onRegister: YaPNdT1UYCU719GXGoboROTUx1u1
```

the log of ios simulator:

```
register clicked
register clicked
before register userid: 
in registerUser
Registering with account: Test2215@gmail.com-12352132
after await in _onRegister:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I have checked and note this for people have a problem like me.
Don't use web config for mobile (I have learned on Youtube and some series they taught me like that). Instead of that use firebase